# Running an Apache Spark Program on YARN from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have set up Apache Spark 1.1.1 to run on YARN (Hadoop-2.5.2). I am able to run programs using the `spark-submit` command.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14. I am able to build artifacts and run the resulting jar using `spark-submit`.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to run the entire program directly from IntelliJ?

I added the necessary libraries and activated the hadoop-2.4 profile. However, I end up getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCredentials()Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/Credentials;
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientBase$class.$init$(ClientBase.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.<init>(Client.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:53)
at WordCountWorkFlow.main(WordCountWorkFlow.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: No i did not. Right now, I am building artifacts of my project and running it using spark-submit.

Comment: Btw, when you build artifacts, what steps did you do? Do you include the depencies? A simple jar ends up being 100MB for me...

Comment: While making use of IntelliJ idea, I just add the compile output to the artifacts, in addition to the suggested maven libraries. The size is around 13.8 KB.

Comment: have a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449004/how-to-run-a-spark-example-program-in-intellij-idea

Comment: You are using sbt or maven for building package?

Comment: Also this may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326459/hadoop-classnotfoundexception. It seems the `hadoop-core.jar` is not in the classpath

Comment: You can use `sc.getConf.setMaster("local")`

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij you have to add the dependencies which is path of your Hadoop conf dir

go to project setting and in dependencies add the path 
$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

and if you are using any lambda then from project setting ->sources -> language level set 8-lambda type annonation [image]